# Is there an equation to describe translation and rotation?

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems

Suppose a free rod, $l=2r$, is hit on a tip T and translates with $v= 1r/s$ and at the same time rotates with angular velocity $\omega= 1rad/s$. Is there an equation that can determine the position of point T at any time?

If there is none, can we describe this complex motion without using matrices?

I have drawn a sketch:
[image]

The curve looks a half ellipsis, but I can't be sure.

**update**

- what is the difference between an ellipsis and a cycloid? is a cycloid an ellipsis?
- if the rotational speed exceeds the translational v, the curve makes a loop. Can the equation still describe the motion?

[image]

Comment: Are you using $r$ as both a length and as a symbol for radians?

Comment: @user77434: It sounds as if you're describing a _cycloid_; in any case, yes, it should be possible to describe the motion using parametric formulas, and you should now have enough rep to post an image. :)

Comment: @user77434  Yes, write rad.  I would express the units in terms of radians per second to distinguish the two different uses of $r$.  By the way, you now have enough reputation to post the image you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can write $T$ as $c + \frac{l}{2}(\sin \theta, \cos\theta)$ where $c$ is the position of the center of mass and $\theta$ is the orientation of the rod.

Assuming that $c(0) = (0,0),\ \theta(0) = 0$, and that the rod moves right and spins clockwise (your diagram doesn't look quite right, almost as if you had hit the tip opposite $T$), then we have

$T(t) = \left(t +\frac{l}{2} \sin t, \frac{l}{2} \cos t\right)$

which for $l=2$ looks like

[image]

Comment: Yes, this equation works no matter what the velocity and angular velocity. The general curve is called a trochoid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochoid.
The figure was made using Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @user77434 I clicked on the "share" button and then "create permanent shareable page."

Comment: Could you give me the link to wolfram with the question that produced this image?